# Unity - OnMouseDown double click

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have four GameObjects in the game I am making and when I click on each one a dialogue box opens.

My problem is that I am using OnMouseDown and the first one always need to be clicked twice. It happens just on the OnMouseDown, I have buttons on the game that work just fine.

```
public static GameObject selectedClient;
public bool isBuying;

private Manager manager;

private void Start()
{
    manager = GameObject.FindObjectOfType(typeof(Manager)) as Manager;
}

private void OnMouseDown()
{
    if (isBuying == true)
    {
        selectedClient = this.gameObject;
        manager.Talk();
    }
    else if (isBuying == false)
    {
        manager.NotTalk();
    }
}
```

The Talk() and NotTalk() are as follows:

```
    public void Talk()
{
    dialogueBox.SetActive(true);
    Time.timeScale = 0f;
    actualClient = Client.selectedClient;
}

public void NotTalk()
{
    dialogueBox.SetActive(false);
    Time.timeScale = 1f;
}
```

Someone knows why this happens?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Not sure how to help without your code

Comment: Sorry, added the code. It works perfectly after the first double click, but gets an error if I click on one object and then on other, that's why I want to fix this.

Comment: We don't put "Solved" in the title.  Accepting an answer is good enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, it seems that `OnMouseDown()` and `Talk()` is being called successfully on the first mouse click, but a second mouse click is required to get the `dialogueBox` to show.

If `dialogueBox.SetActive(true)` is being called successfully, you could take a look at the Unity Scene Hierarchy window to see if it became active like you expect after the first mouse click. If it did, then you can examine that object to see why it's not appearing on screen. (As another poster mentioned, it may be related to `dialogueBox` initialization.)

Also, these questions might help us debug and figure out the issue:

- What error do you get when you "click on one object and then on other"?
- What happens if you click the buttons in a different order? If there are 4 buttons, is it the first button that is always affected, or the first button that you click?

In general, as other posters have suggested, using `Debug.Log` and `Debug.Assert` should help you narrow down the issue. Similarly, you can set breakpoints in the code and step through to see if the code is running like you expect. And as I mentioned in this post, the Unity Scene Hierarchy window is useful for debugging as well.

Comment: You are right about the dialogueBox; when I click the first time on the NPC the time stops but the dialogue don't become active on the Hierarchy Window.

About the questions: It's not really a Unity error, just a little bug; when I click on the first NPC and then click on the second, the second gets selected. It's not really something that breaks the game, but it is annoying seeing that it should not be working like that.

Comment: How about debugging using [MonoBehaviour::OnEnable](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnEnable.html)? This should be called whenever `SetActive(true)` is called. Similarly, there is OnDisable(). (For full details, see [Unity's Manual on Execution Order](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ExecutionOrder.html). That will help us identify if OnEnable() is firing as we expect. Perhaps something is calling `gameObject.SetActive(false)` from somewhere else.

Comment: As for the little bug you mentioned, I'm not sure if I understand the bug. If you click on the second NPC, shouldn't it get selected assuming `isBuying` is true on that NPC? (Unless there is some kind of check using `selectedClient` that isn't shown in your post.) If that's not the expected behaviour, that could be worth debugging as well as it could be related to this issue.

Comment: I have to thank you for your answers, I found the problem. In the DialogueBox script there was a SetActive(false) on the Start method, just in case the DialogueBox started the game activated. I am a beginner on the programmer/game development area and never knew the GameObject had to be activated for the script to start. I truly thank you.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming `manager.Talk()` opens the dialog, perhaps `isBuying` is false initially, and is toggled when you click once?

Edit: User updated question with `Talk` and `NotTalk` methods.

Since your say that initially, only the time stops, but the dialogueBox doesn't show, by any chance, is this because it isn't populated, or correctly initialized? Can you show is code of what your expect to show up?

It may just be that dialogueBox has nothing to display, and therefore, doesn't, however, by the second click, it somehow it's correctly populated and can display.

Comment: Sorry for not specifying that. The manager.Talk( ) opens the dialog and stops the game. isBuying is false initially and is toggled by animation (when the NPC stops walking, the isBuying turns true).

If I just click once the time stops but the dialogue box doesn't, as if just half of the Talk( ) worked.

Comment: I suggest you type `Debug.Assert(isBuying)` at the beginning of your `OnMouseDown()`. This will allow you to see whether the boolean is even being correctly set. If what you say holds correct, when you're NPC stops moving, the boolean should forever remain true. This might let us know if it keeps changing by sooner unknown factor, which may be causing problems for `Manager`.

Comment: The isBuying bool changes based on animation, it's false while the NPC is walking and true when it stops. I tried the Debug.Assert(isBuying) but it returns nothing on both clicks, even if the second works, I'm doing something wrong? It's the first time I use it.

Answer (score 0):

Add a Debug.log(isBuying); above (isBuying == true).

Then you'll know if the OnMouseDown() is being called in the first place and if it proceeds like you expect it to. After that, you should probably be able to fix it yourself, otherwise, please let me know what you found.

Comment: Excuse me for this, but don't you mean `Debug.Assert(isBuying)`? Additionally, the user states that `OnMouseDown` is called, but one specific button needs to be double pressed as opposed to the expected single press.

Comment: Tried it on the OnMouseDown( ) and on the Update( ), everything seems normal.

OnMouseDown( ) really needs two clicks on the mouse to work, even if the first click is recognized.

I'm going to add the Talk( ) and NotTalk( ) on the question, maybe it helps.

Comment: Could you try and comment out the timeScale adjustments and check if it does work properly when you're not pausing the game?